# How to set dynamic model association without foreign key cakephp3

Tags: model-associations, cakephp-3.4

I am using cakephp 3.4.

I need to retrieve the data from two tables where no any association between them. I need to have solution where I can bind 2 models dynamically for that particular query.

There is an option to bind-unbind model, but that is an old method.

If there are 2 tables i.e. `Articles` and `Authors` without any relations/association, I could be able to find `Author` record while querying on `Articles`.

Comment: You have a way to `join` the two tables in question? The query builder has a `join` function that allows you to specify this for a single query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that option is available in model, that means its permanent but I need that join occasionally where its join 2 tables for that single query only where no relation between 2 tables..

Comment: You're thinking of the associations. I'm talking about the [`join` function](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins).